# Disable Seek on vimeo player

Tags: javascript, vimeo

I need to disable seek on the vimeo embeded player. It seems the only answer is to use setCurrentTime on a seeked event. The problem is that it gets thrown into an infinite loop. Maybe because timeupdate also gets triggered on the seek.

```
this.player.on('timeupdate', this.vimeoPlayProgress.bind(this));
this.player.on('seeked', this.vimeoSeek.bind(this));
```

Then in vimeoSeek:

```
var player = this.player;
var playTime = this.vimeoPlayTime;
player.setCurrentTime(playTime).then(function (seconds) {
                ...

            });
```

Comment: Any solution to that? I have the same problem.

Comment: There is none. Talked to vimeo customer support and they said it's not possible. Only work around is to use the direct links to the vimeo hosted videos and make your own player.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it as below, but there is a problem with it during buffering time, as mentioned here: https://github.com/vimeo/player.js/issues/61

```
    var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);
    var priorTimeUpdateTime = 0;

    player.on('seeked', function() {
        player.pause().then(function() {
            player.getCurrentTime().then(function(seconds) {
                //console.log('seconds: '+ seconds + ' priorTimeUpdateTime: ' + priorTimeUpdateTime);  
                if (seconds > priorTimeUpdateTime) {
                    player.setCurrentTime(priorTimeUpdateTime).then(function(seconds) {

                        // seconds = the actual time that the player seeked to

                    }).catch(function(error) {
                        switch (error.name) {
                            case 'RangeError':
                                // the time was less than 0 or greater than the video’s duration     
                                break;
                            default:
                                // some other error occurred
                                break;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).catch(function(error) {
                // an error occurred
                console.log('Vimeo API error');
            });
        });
        player.play();
    });

    player.on('ended', function() {
        alert('Do something at the end!');
    });

    setInterval(function() {
        player.getCurrentTime().then(function(seconds2) {
            priorTimeUpdateTime = seconds2;
            //console.log('Playhead Update: ' + priorTimeUpdateTime);
        }).catch(function(error) {
            // an error occurred
            console.log('Vimeo API error');
        });
    }, 15000)
```

Comment: Earlier this year, Vimeo added a `seeking` getter, has anyone successfully used that to disable seeking ahead in a video?